# css.scss file don't create in rails app when use scaffold in assets/stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
terminal$ rails g scaffold Foo name:string description:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20150901182647_create_foos.rb
  create    app/models/foo.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/foo_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/foos.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :foos
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/foos
  create      app/views/foos/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/foos/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/foos/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/foos/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/foos/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/controllers/foos_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/foos_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  invoke    jbuilder
  create      app/views/foos/index.json.jbuilder
  create      app/views/foos/show.json.jbuilder
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/foos.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/foos.scss
  invoke  scss
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.scss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4 update they have removed .css.scss extension format while creating style sheet files. Now on wards only .scss files will be created.

Though still If you want to use .css.scss then you can rename those file by yourself.

> sass compiler by default will look for file.scss and compile them
>   while in production as .css.scss

Comment: Now you have to use scss format of css. See this to understand Sass(scss) http://sass-lang.com/guide.

Comment: If you want to write css code then you have to rename that file to css.scss. then no need to learn sass

Comment: Thanks,it helped me a lot